# MathJax does not show the equations properly

Tags: support, mathjax

I tried to [answer a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/767090) and in the edit mode MathJax shows the equations properly, but when I click on "save" some equations are not rendered (?) at all, and I see only the MathJax code.

If I click on *edit* again, everything seems to be OK, but in normal viewing mode it is screwed up on my [Brave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_(web_browser)) or [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge) browsers. I tried to edit again, start a new answer, etc., but I still had the same problem. What is wrong with my equations?

Comment: Related info on the inconsistency between MathJax preview and final render: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389459/334566 Also see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35383/207316 for some general info from the lead MathJax developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the use of `\label{}`. Here is your first equation, with and without that command:

$$ h(t)\nabla \times \tilde {\mathbf H} = \mathbf J +\epsilon_0 \dot {e}(t) \tilde {\mathbf E} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

$$ h(t)\nabla \times \tilde {\mathbf H} = \mathbf J +\epsilon_0 \dot {e}(t) \tilde {\mathbf E} \tag{1}$$

Both look identical during editing, but the first is sometimes (but inconsistently) mangled in the output.

I'm unaware of how `\label{}` works in MathJax, and whether it is truly supported. But do you really need it? Why not use just `\tag{}`s, and hard-code any references in the text? (i.e. use `$(1)$` instead of `$\eqref{1}$`.)

Comment: Why? I am not even a rank amateur in mathjax; I have seen used \label, \eqref, etc. successfully, and I have tried to do the same. Until now have had no problem. From here on, I will just do what you have told me above. The down side of dropping \label and \eqref is that I lose the live link. Thank  you.

Comment: I'm not sure. See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5396/ for a post by a MathJax developer, though -- it provides alternative code to hyperlink references, but it makes it sound like `\eqref{}` should work. I don't know why it's not working here.

Comment: Just fixed my post and being a practical man it is good enough for me from here on that your suggestion worked immediately. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to \tag{}. I wasn't aware of this command.

Comment: @LoganJ.Fisher On my Linux+Firefox system I can right click over Mathjax and it gives me the option to display the Mathjax itself.  It's a useful way to pick up new tricks when you see an expression that interests you.